# Workflow OAuth 1.0a in PHP

Tags: php, security, oauth

I've been trying to understand OAuth for a while and I'm still left with some questions on the workflow and suggestions for handling values used. I'm working on a PHP three-legged OAuth 1.0a project for learning purposes. The steps I'll be referring to are described here; http://wiki.oauth.net/w/page/12238555/Signed%20Callback%20URLs

1. Why is in step 5 a token returned? I thought the token was already known with the consumer, just like the token_secret. So it used as an identifier about which request the consumer sends data? Or am I mistaken by thinking the token sent is the same request token as sent in step 2?
2. The callback URL is listed as optional here, but on other specs it's deemed required. I was thinking about letting people store their callback URL in the service provider's database, since it won't change often or not at all and thus not send it in step 1 and retrieve it from the database in step 5.
3. Since the RSA hashing method is discouraged because of speed and possible leaks, everyone decides to go with the HMAC method. Do we need a hashing method send in steps 1 and 6 then? Moreover, I see very few service providers that offer an other method.
4. Making hashes with mt_rand() isn't safe, so I was thinking about using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(), is it safe e.g. as a key for a hash with hash_hmac()?
5. I often see sha1 used for request and access tokens and secret_tokens. Isn't a longer hash like sha256 or sha512 much safer? The storage space must not be a problem if safety extends by it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Even if the token is known to the consumer, you have to know on which OAuth session the returned user is operating on. In this step the token acts as a session identifier. Otherwise how would you know who the returned user is (unless you provide a session identifier in the callback yourself).
2. I advise you to adhere to the specification. Since you don't control the Consumer if you are acting as a Service Provider, you don't know anything about the callback requirements. If it is dynamic (e.g. including a session identifier like in 1.), you will have problems with a stored callback.
3. Again. Stick to the spec. Although it is not written in stone, a lot of smart people have been working on it and thinking long and hard about the implications of changes to the spec. Since one might not control both domains (Service Provider and Consumer), you have to agree on an authentication method. How would the domains know how to interpret the ciphers if they don't know about the method? What if the current methods are deemed unsecure? How do you find out if one party changed the method?
4. This function is supposed to be cryptographically secure. You can use it.
5. You can use a stronger hash, sure. You probably should. Make sure both domains understand the method. See http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor45